# jQuery trigger('click') Not Working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, blueimp, jquery-click-event, jquery-trigger

I previously had the following

```
$('#refresh').click(function () {
        $('#fileUpload').trigger('click');
});
```

However I've changed it so it should fire on a query parameter

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(function () {
    var param = getParameterByName('upload');
    if (param == "yes") {
        $('#fileUpload').trigger('click');
    };
});
```

It works in FireFox and IE but not Chrome. Any idea why?

Comment: what it returns getParameterByName('upload') ?

Comment: if the `#fileUpload` element is an `input type="file"`, then you will encounter security issues faking events on it in Chrome.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is there anyway around this? It works fine in the first instance

Comment: If you want to submit a form you could use $( "#formname" ).submit(); , else you could run the function you want to run on $('#fileUpload').trigger('click'); by calling it directly with functionName();

Answer (score 1):

You can't trigger the action of a file upload input using JavaScript due to security limitations in some browsers.

So showing the file selection modal is not possible to prompt based on url.

An alternative would be to show your own light box / modal which contains only a strong call to action to upload followed by an input field or a  button which masks an input field. Make it the primary and sole function of the page so as to make it as simple understand and to complete as possible.